# How to stop a JTextField from getting re-sized in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am creating a GUI with grid layout. I have added the JTextFields, JButtons and everything to it DIRECTLY. For an example, like this,

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Hello"):
JButton b2 = new JButton("Bye");
JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
JTextField t2 = new JTextField(10);

GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2,2,2,2);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(grid);
panel.add(b1);
panel.add(t1);
panel.add(b2);
panel.add(t2);
```

In here, if the user resizes the window everything appears very large. The only other way I know to prevent these from getting these is adding all of each and everything to seperate JPanel which has FlowLayout. But thats not practical because if there are 20 stuff, there will be 20 JPanels. I tried setting the maximum size, minimum size and all, and they didnt change any. Please help.

Comment: you should use more complex GridBagLayout with constraints or disable resizing.

Comment: `GroupLayout` would be a better fit for this.  The natural approach of `GridLayout` is to make everything the same size.

Comment: Ya, GridBag Layout would be the best option, but personally, I don't like to mess with it. That's why I always go for other layouts. However, if I couldn't solve this by following answers, that would be my only option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. not possible with plain [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), because this is basic feature of this Layout Manager
2. use proper Layout Manager [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or todays [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)
3. very simple way is by using [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html)

Comment: I am interested..But Oracle says "SpringLayout is, however, very low-level and as such you really should only use it with a GUI builder, rather than attempting to code a spring layout manager by hand." What do you think?

Comment: funny description, then valid espacially for GridBagLayout, btw if you have any doubts then look ad MigLayout :-)

Answer (score 2):

@mKorbel and @Logan have a point in their answers, but if you for some reason really really REALLY need to use a GridLayout and you really need the JTextField to stay a certain size then you can do so by putting the JTextField inside a JPanel with a BorderLayout.

```
JTextField fixedWidthField = new JTextField();
JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
fieldPanel.add(fixedWidthField, BorderLayout.WEST);

GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2,2,2,2);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(grid);
panel.add(b1);
panel.add(fieldPanel);
panel.add(b2);
panel.add(t2);
```

We all recommend you use a more advanced layout manager. I personally like TableLayout but you need to download an extra Jar file for that.

Comment: +1 for nesting. The `JPanel` default, `FlowLayout`, is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of gridLayout. I'm not sure its easy to stop it. I would use gridBagLayout instead. You can set the fill to none for each cell it has. It is more difficult at first, but it is all I use now.